# Types of Magnets to use for Bluetooth and electronics circuits

Tags: bluetooth, magnet

I am working on a project requiring Bluetooth capability. In order to make it convenient, it would be great to have a magnet in order for it to stick to things. I was just wondering if it is possible to use a magnet without damaging or affecting the electronics. Is there a magnet type that could be considered?

Comment: Just don't worry about it, take any magnet you can reach within your budget

Comment: The magnet would produce a stead-state magnetic field, so by faraday's law V=-N dflux/dt, the dflux/dt term = 0.

Comment: If the device uses any ferrites (filters, transformers etc), then a modest external field from a magnet may saturate them shifting their inductance. I don't know whether commercial BT modules contain such components, being built down to a price an'all, but many radio frequency devices do!

Answer (score 3):

A magnet produces a static magnetic field (or even if you moved it as fast as you could, an extremely steady one), so that doesn't interfere at all with radio waves.

You'd be getting into trouble if your magnet was so strong that it lead to nonlinear effects. But unless you plan to affix your bluetooth device using an MRI, I doubt you'll be able to measure these effects without a lot of research budget at all.